# A problem involving the definition of composite functions and its derivative.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives

The problem goes like this:
Given $f(x)=5x+3$ a function $g(x)$ differentiable on $x=8$ and $(g∘f)'(1)=2$
Calculate $g'(8)$

I reached to 2 different solutions using 2 different methods, the first method gave me the wrong answer, the second gave me the correct, what i want to know is where is the mistake or the misconception that occurred during the first method.

method 1:

$(g∘f)(x)=g(f(x)$

$(g∘f)'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}[g(f(x))]$

$(g∘f)'(1)=\frac{d}{dx}[g(f(1))]$

but we already know that $(g∘f)'(1)=2$

$2=\frac{d}{dx}[g(5(1)+3)]$

$2=\frac{d}{dx}[g(8)]$

$2=g'(8)$

This was not the solution provided by my teacher, it was instead $\frac{2}{5}$, i understand that you can reach to such result by using the chain rule:

method 2

$(g∘f)'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}[g(f(x))]=g'(f(x))*f'(x)$

given that $f'(x)=5$, then

$(g∘f)'(x)=5 \cdot g'(f(x))$

$(g∘f)'(1)=5 \cdot g'(f(1))$

$2=5 \cdot g'(8)$

$\frac{2}{5}=g'(8)$

But what i dont understand is where i made a mistake in the first method, i would appreciate if someone could point my mistake.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

We use *Chain Rule* to solve this problem.

Your mistake was you did not follow the Chain Rule.

Kindly recall the Chain Rule given as follows:
$$
(g \circ f)'(x) = {d \over dx} \left[ (g \circ f)(x) \right]
= g'(f(x)) f'(x) \tag{1}
$$

We put $x = 1$ in (1), which gives
$$
(g \circ f)'(1) = g'(f(1)) f'(1) \tag{2}
$$

Given in the problem that
$$
(g \circ f)'(1) = 2 \tag{3}
$$

Since $f(x) = 5 x + 3$, we find that
$$
f(1) = 8 \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ f'(1) = 5 \tag{4}
$$

Substituting (3) and (4) into (2), we get
$$
2 = g'(8) (5)
$$
or
$$
g'(8) = {2 \over 5}
$$